# Will Google AdSense allow for more than one 300x600 ad on a single page?

Tags: google-adsense

With the new AdSense rules, can webmasters have more than one 300X600 ad on a single page for desktop if the content justifies it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can place an unlimited amount of ads on the page per Googles [per this article](https://wpquads.com/google-adsense-allowed-number-ads/)

> It was 3 ads for content units and 3 ads for link units. (Some premium partners were allowed to serve up to 6 ad units)  Recently in August 2016 Google updated this policy  You can now place an unlimited amount of AdSense ads on a page